# Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following is my code

```
Select drpCounty = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("county")));
drpCounty.selectByVisibleText("Bedfordshire");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check visibility of elements:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("county")));
Select drpCounty = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("county")));
drpCounty.selectByVisibleText("Bedfordshire");
```